# Cannot get correct return object.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

```
serviceApp.factory('xml2json', function() {

return {
Convert: function(path) {
  var fs = require('fs');
  var xml2js = require('xml2js');
  var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
  var json;

    fs.readFile(path, function(err, data) {
      parser.parseString(data, function(err, result) {
        json = result.object.property[9].steps[0].object[27].property[1].property[0].object;
        console.log(json);
      });
    });
    console.log(json + '1');
    return json;
  }
}
});
```

Here is my service^^ For whatever reason, the first console log works just fine, as intended. The second one is undefined. When I return json, it returns undefined. I've tried timers, I've tried promises, I've tried callbacks. I don't know how the hell to make this return the result from parser.parseString(); Please help.

```
serviceApp.controller('PPQACtrl', function($scope, SqlConFactory, CreateRequest, EmailService, xml2json) {
    var path = '/some/path/to/file.xml'
    var myjson = xml2json.Convert(path);
    console.log(myjson);


});
```

Comment: `fs.readFile` and `parser.parseString` are "async," so they return automatically.

Comment: thanks for that, I've already read and tried a lot of things in that article. I'm still doing something wrong.

Yes I know they're async and return immediately. I've tried forcing setTimeout and callbacks, and promises. Please read my original post. I'm not understanding something about this implementation and why none of those solutions are working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since the call is async - you can either use a promise or callback to return the data. Here's an example of your code refactored to use a callback:

Service:

```
serviceApp.factory('xml2json', function() {
    return {
        Convert: function(path, callback) {
            var fs = require('fs');
            var xml2js = require('xml2js');
            var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
            var json;

            fs.readFile(path, function(err, data) {
                parser.parseString(data, function(err, result) {
                    json = result.object.property[9].steps[0].object[27].property[1].property[0].object;
                    callback(json);
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And the usage:

```
xml2json.Convert(path, function(json) {
    console.log(json);
});
```